# Opening request value-based view without repeating code

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

I am trying to open different views based upon a request value. For example, if the value of `$request` is set to one, then view one should open. If the `$request` value is two, then view two should open.

My code is working fine, but right now, I will have to repeat code for each view. How can I do it without repeating the *if* condition?

**Scenario**

```php
public function printreports(Request $request)
{
    $reports = $request->get('reports');

    if ($reports === 1) {
        return view('teachers.report1', compact('anything'));
    }

    if ($reports === 2) {
        return view('teachers.report2', compact('anything'));
    }
}
```

Comment: use `if` with `else if` and `else` or use `switch` case.

Comment: i have 20 views, then i will have to type if else 20 times? yes please how switch case would return required view. without repeating everything.

Comment: in `switch` you have to write 20 cases as well. you have 20 views with may be 20 different name and folder location. so there's nothing more you can do actually.

Comment: please check solution, answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large amount of files with similar name pattern:

```
$viewName = sprintf('teachers.report%d', $request->get('reports', 1))

if (!\View::exists($viewName)) {
   ___ throw an error or return default view ____
}

return view($viewName, compact('anything'));
```

Comment: $request->get('reports', 1)) --- even if i don't write ,1  i am getting same result, what is purpose of 1 in this case?

Comment: It's a default value in case nothing was present in the request